# Can an Outlook 2010 calendar generate ical feeds to be imported by another system

Tags: drupal, calendar, outlook, icalendar, outlook-2010

I'd like for my Drupal site to have a calendar that's synced to an external Outlook calendar.  The data entry is happening on the Outlook calendar side, so I'd like for the sync to go FROM Outlook to my Drupal site.

I have found a lot of information about this already: how to subscribe to ical feeds on Outlook (but that gets data to and not from Outlook.  sigh), how to sync my Outlook calendar with google calendar, etc.

However, I have not found information on how to get an iCal feed that originates from my Outlook calendar.  Is that just because it can't be done or have I just not looked in the right places :-).

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your outlook data synced with a google calendar already then you could display the google calendar with the fullcalendar module, starting with version 2.

http://drupal.org/node/1056752

Comment: Hey Harald, I don't have Outlook synced with Google.  It's good that there's at least that as an option for a last resort, but would rather not do Outlook --> Google --> Drupal site.  Any ideas if Outlook has an option to generate iCal feeds that Drupal can accept directly?

Comment: I've been ms free for over a decade so i can only judge by popular consensus displayed on the internet and searching there tells me no.

Comment: I just tried this and it does work.  Still can't be my solution because the Outlook calendar we're trying to sync is a shared calendar (not a user's default calendar) and Google Calendar Sync only sync's the users' default calendar to the default Google calendar (doesn't give you an option to sync any of the shared calendars you have), but this is a nice idea.  So +1.  Wanted to let you know I tried it.

Comment: that's too bad, sorry I couldn't be of more assistance. :( I hope oberron's solution works out great.

Answer (score 1):

if your outlook server has an outlook web access (OWA) then you could use the Exchange Web Service to synch your drupal site to your outlook.
there is at least one open source project here: http://davmail.sourceforge.net/ for inspirations on details.

Comment: Thanks, oberron.  This is a very good idea, but it'll be a little overkill for us, because we're only trying to export and sync a couple of Outlook calendars to our drupal site.  Really appreciate your idea though!